# What frequency is needed for pair production?

Tags: pair-production

I'd like to know exactly what frequency of a photon produces a pair e+/ e- , is it 2,4712x 10^20: must the photon have exactly that frequency or is there a range of tolerance?

When the 2 particles merge they produce 2 separate photons, right?, does that mean we split the photon in two, or is some energy lost? what is the exact frequency of the two photons produced? I figured out 1,2356 x 10^20 , do you have the exact number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the photon frequency needed is 2,4712 x 10^20 Hz which corresponds to the energy of an electron and a positron. However, keep in mind that all conservation laws must be fullfilled, in particular energy and momentum. Because of this, a single photon can not undergo pair production in free space, but it is possible in proximity of a nucleus for example. Any extra energy the photon  has (any higher its frequecy) will be carried by the e+/e- as kinetic energy.
Also, depending on the energy other particle pairs might get created. For example if the energy is above 211 MeV a muon anti-muon pair can be created since the mass of a muon is about 105 MeV/c^2.

> When the 2 particles merge they produce 2 separate photons, right?

Again, if particles annihilate the can create all sorts of other particles, depending on the energy. For low energy 2 photon production dominates (you need at least 2 photons to conserve energy and momentum). When you have higher energies you can create all other charged particle anti-particle pairs.

As trula said, there are loads of resources on this topic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production

Comment: thanks, if I got it right you say there is a wide range of frequencies, what is in excess goes into Ke, right?

Comment: the exact value is : 2.471**199**2763337798, 2x 1.2355899638

Comment: @charlie: Yes correct.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of momentum forbids that a photon with momentum hf/c produces a pair with momentum 0 or two momentums in opposite directions, so it happens only close to some atom which can take the momentum. But you find all this and more precise discussions if you just google pair production or Electron–positron annihilation.